# How to tell if a Windows group has a well known SID and what that SID is

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the Well Known SID (if it exists) from a group name.

So far I have:

```
$group = 'Administrators'

$account = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($group)
$sid = $account.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
```

This gives me the Sid object for the group which has a method 'IsWellKnown', so far so good.  If I feed it a list of well known sids I've copied from the web, this works.

Web link here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype(v=vs.110).aspx

```
$wks = 'list from the web'
foreach ($s in $wks){ $sid.IsWellKnown($s)}
```

I don't want to have the list of well known sids copied from a web page, I'd like to find them out programmatically.  I can sort of do it by making the IsWellKnown method error out with nonsense:

```
$sid.IswellKnown('*')
```

Will give me an error message with the list I need inside.  Obviously I don't want to get the list from an error message I want to get it properly, does anyone know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Enum]::GetValues([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType])
```